# Static file to map IP to MAC addresses

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ip, network-interface

I created a mesh network.

Sometimes the ARP, IPv4 based applications, or even ping do not correctly respond, any suggestion? Actually, I require to create a file (i.e whatever) that contains `IP -> MAC Address`, such as the following:

```
10.0.0.1 01:23:45:67:89:AB
10.0.0.2 01:23:45:67:89:CD
```

Then I can find my PCs/Laptops with those address---without requiring `arp` command.

Comment: This is more of a networking question than a Unix/Linux question but `arp` and `ping` not working could be the cause of several issues. You can just add static IP addresses to the machines which you can find out how to do from many of the questions on this site or by using Google. It may still not resolve the issue of ping not working.

Comment: Please let us know, are you working on a virtual machine or your hosting Linux OS on a physical machine? Also provide detailed information, such as the distribution of your Linux machine, and so on.

Comment: @EsmaeilMirzaee they are individual physical linux machines. Distributions are latest debian linux. Regards...

Comment: You could do worse than install `arpwatch`.

Answer (score 0):

Having different MACs for certain IPs is exactly the reason for Errors like 'ARP is not working', or 'Ping does not work'.

The reason: Managed Ethernet Switches can be configured to implement a "flap Limit" for MACs changing their port too often. So in your case, the duplicate IP may trigger such a measure. Unmanaged Switches may imply a rate-Limit for flapping by themselves.

Do you have These MACs on seperate Hosts, or on seperate Cards?

Making sure to use one IP on one Host/NIC only will prevent you from experiencing These Errors.

Comment: Sorry about that. They will be 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2. Corrected the question.

Comment: Ah, is see, you've edited the addresses. So my Suggestion is: you are running the VMs on host-only or NAT (Network Adapter Settings). If you want full Access to the VMs, please Switch to "bridged Networking". This will help.

Comment: I have two physical machines. I am not on VMs.

Comment: Open a terminal on all boxes, and start "watch arp -a". Then ping the machines from each other, and watch the Output. What happens?